# App Insights - Pivot result

Tags: azure-application-insights, ms-app-analytics

How can I pivot the result of a App Insights analytics query?

For example i would like to have a value-column for every `cloud_RoleInstace`:

```
performanceCounters  
| where timestamp > todatetime("2017-07-24T13:44:00.251Z")  
    and timestamp < todatetime("2017-07-24T13:49:00.251Z")   
| where name in ("% Processor Time")//, "Request Execution Time")  
| sort by timestamp asc nulls last  
| project timestamp, value, cloud_RoleInstance
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, just add

```
| evaluate pivot(cloud_RoleInstance)
```

or possibly more complicated but maybe more correct:

```
| summarize value=sum(value) by bin(timestamp, 1m), cloud_RoleInstance 
| evaluate pivot(cloud_RoleInstance, sum(value))
```

to your query :)

also, you can simplify the time part of your query to use the `between` operator

```
| where timestamp between(todatetime("2017-07-24T13:44:00.251Z")..todatetime"2017-07-24T13:49:00.251Z")
```

Comment: quick question: can summarize `count()` with pivot? im only getting 0's and 1's, which i believe signifies presence or absence of a value for that given line?

Comment: it looks like you can do `pivot(cloud_RoleInstance, sum(value)` , from the docs it looks like only `count` and `sum` are currently supported?

Comment: no luck there john... `pivot(column, count())` returns same 0's and 1's...

Comment: yes count was the default (what you saw first).  you could change your query to do `summarize sum(value) by timestamp(bin, 1m), cloud_RoleInstance`  and then use `sum(value)` in the pivot?

Comment: only 0 and 1?   if i do `| evaluate pivot(cloud_RoleInstance, sum(value))` i see 0's and numbers that are not 1 and lots of rows. if i do `| summarize value=sum(value) by bin(timestamp, 1m), cloud_RoleInstance
| evaluate pivot(cloud_RoleInstance, sum(value))` i get one row for each minute, with the sum of that perfcounter during that minute for each role instance.

Comment: great, updated the answer with some of that stuff.  the query language is pretty amazing once you get the hang of it, and i swear that team adds operators and functions daily!